error while use this package flutter_otp_text_field

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... lib/otp.dart:18:13: Error: The
method 'OTPTextField' isn't defined for the class 'OTPScreen'.

'OTPScreen' is from 'package:idoraza_task/otp.dart' ('lib/otp.dart'). Try correcting the name to the name of an existing
method, or defining a method named 'OTPTextField'.
OTPTextField(
^^^^^^^^^^^^ lib/otp.dart:25:30: Error: The getter 'FieldStyle' isn't defined for the class 'OTPScreen'.
'OTPScreen' is from 'package:idoraza_task/otp.dart' ('lib/otp.dart'). Try correcting the name to the name of an existing
getter, or defining a getter or field named 'FieldStyle'.
otpFieldStyle: FieldStyle.box,  // Assuming this is the correct property
^^^^^^^^^^ Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


while using this package I encountered a error
I had tried  OTPPinField also , but same problem arise
